# How do I deploy nuget packages in Travis CI?

Tags: deployment, nuget, travis-ci

I have a nuget package that runs Travis CI for its builds.  Here is my yml:

```
language: csharp
solution: TreasureGen.sln
install:
  - nuget restore TreasureGen.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Runners -OutputDirectory testrunner
script:
  - xbuild TreasureGen.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5" /p:Configuration=Stress
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Unit/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Unit.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Tables/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Tables.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Stress/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Stress.dll
```

Ideally, when this runs on the master branch, if it is successful, it would then deploy the nuget packages as needed.  There are already Nuget projects in the solution, which contain `Package.nuspec` and `NuGet.config` files for each package.  I have tried getting it to deploy myself and have not had much success - typically I run into problems with the authentication, but not exclusively.  I was wondering if anyone here has deployed nuget packages like this in Travis and how they did it.

Comment: Hello. I hope that you have found a solution to your problem, but if not I will suggest this article http://timveletta.com/2017-04-03-building-and-deploying-your-nuget-package-with-travis-ci/

Comment: Thanks methgaard - the article is helpful, but unfortunately does fall short.  It would not allow me to specify to publish only particular branches (master), and did not have a way to pull the build version from a nuspec file (probably doable, just not immediately apparent)

Comment: Well, regarding publishing a specific branch, this should be done with the branch tag in your `.travis.yaml`?

Comment: Branch tags only work in `deploy` sections, as far as my research shows, while the article uses the `script` section to do the deployment

Comment: Have you looked at the `on` tag? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment

Comment: Again, that tag exists under the `deploy` header, while the article details its operations under the `script` header, because Travis doesn't officially support deployment to NuGet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After much fiddling and experimentation, I finally found a solution.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: csharp
solution: TreasureGen.sln
install:
  - nuget restore TreasureGen.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Runners -OutputDirectory testrunner
script:
  - xbuild TreasureGen.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5" /p:Configuration=Stress
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Unit/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Unit.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Tables/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Tables.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Stress/bin/Stress/TreasureGen.Tests.Integration.Stress.dll
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: chmod +x ./deploy/deploy.sh && ./deploy/deploy.sh $NUGET_API_KEY $NUGET_SOURCE
  on:
    branch: master
```

**deploy.sh**

```
ApiKey=$1
Source=$2

nuget pack ./TreasureGen/TreasureGen.nuspec -Verbosity detailed
nuget pack ./TreasureGen.Domain/TreasureGen.Domain.nuspec -Verbosity detailed

nuget push ./DnDGen.TreasureGen.*.nupkg -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey $ApiKey -Source $Source
nuget push ./DnDGen.TreasureGen.Domain.*.nupkg -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey $ApiKey -Source $Source
```

Here are some of the key things to remember:

1. Do not forget the `skip_cleanup: true` - this allows you to reuse
   your previous build command results for your nuget package
2. The `chmod +x ./deploy/deploy.sh` allows for the script to be executable
3. Place your API Key and Source as Travis environment variables.  Especially for the API Key, make sure they are marked to not show in the output
4. Your build may differ (not using nunit for tests, only 1 package to publish, etc.), but the deployment process should be similar.

Comment: I also had to add as the first step in my "script" section a command to update NuGet itself:

```
- sudo nuget update -Self
```

otherwise NuGet won't accept my package because the client's version was too old.

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to test that the version number has changed before pushing to nuget?

Answer (score 2):

My .travis.yml is as below, it deploys correctly to nuget and only does the deploy from master branch. The NUGET_API environment variable is setup to only apply to master branch and not be visible in the build.

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1
before_install:
- sudo apt-get -y install libpam0g-dev
install:
- dotnet restore
script:
- dotnet build -c Release
after_success:
- ./test/setup_test_account.sh
- sudo dotnet test test/Npam.Tests/Npam.Tests.csproj
before_deploy:
- dotnet pack -c Release
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: dotnet nuget push ./src/Npam/bin/Release/Npam.*.nupkg  -k $NUGET_API -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  on:
    branch: master
```

https://github.com/CamW/npam/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't work for me (I don't know why). Following is what worked.

```
language: csharp
solution: [SolutionName].sln
install:
  - curl -L -o nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
  - mono nuget.exe restore [SolutionName].sln
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release [SolutionName].sln
  - mono nuget.exe pack ./[NuspecName].nuspec
  - mono nuget.exe setApiKey $NUGET_API_KEY -Source $NUGET_SOURCE -Verbosity quiet
  - mono nuget.exe push [SolutionName].*.nupkg -Source $NUGET_SOURCE
```

`$NUGET_SOURCE`, `$NUGET_API_KEY` are environment variables defined in Travis.

Comment: How do you manage the nuget package version? Do you manually update it with your source pushes, or is there a way to automatically up the version?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the .travis.yml problem with an aspnetcore web site.  The dotnet CLI now supports commands for nuget push and executing unit testing.  I also determined that the approach of having .travis.yml just call an external bash script makes things a like lot easier:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: csharp
solution: ./SolutionName.sln
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1
script:
- chmod +x ./deploy.sh 
- ./deploy.sh
```

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ev

dotnet build -c $BUILD_CONFIG ./SolutionName.sln

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        if [ "$BUILD_CONFIG" = "debug" ]; 
        then
                dotnet test ./TestProject/TestProject.csproj -v normal --no-build
        else
                echo Skip testing on non-debug build
        fi
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        if [ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" = "false" ] && [ "${TRAVIS_BRANCH}" = "master" ]; 
        then
                dotnet nuget push ./NugetProject/bin/$BUILD_CONFIG/NugetProject.*.nupkg --api-key $NUGET_API_KEY --source $NUGET_SOURCE --skip-duplicate
        else
                echo Skip nuget for non-master build
        fi
fi
```

Hope this helps someone using .NET Core 2.2 and higher.