# Publishing NuGet package to Github

Tags: c#, github, nuget, github-actions

I have a Github repository for a C# Class Library project:
https://github.com/JosepeDev/VarEnc

I've created a NuGet package file through Visual Studio and uploaded it to Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/VarEnc/

How can I link this NuGet package to my GitHub packages?
Should I use Actions?

Comment: What do you mean by linking? You mean adding dependencies or something?

Comment: I want to show them here: https://i.imgur.com/iyucDiJ.png

Answer (score 4):

One of the best way to reach this goal - introduce **CI/CD** into your project/repository.
In your situation it is better to choose cloud solution.

#### Tools

There are a lot of cool instruments for this purpose:

- [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) - cloud solution
- [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) - cloud solution
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) - cloud solution
- [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) - on premise
- Also [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) - cloud solution
- and many other instruments ...

I can describe few tools that I am use.

#### Github Actions

1. In marketplace of Github Actions you can find [template](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-nuget) and example of configuration
2. Also there is soluiton for this [How to push nuget package in GitHub actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889719/how-to-push-nuget-package-in-github-actions)
3. And there is helpful [article](https://netlicensing.medium.com/publish-nuget-packages-using-github-actions-9ac5e97d07d4)

#### AppVeyor

To configure this CI, do the following steps:

1. Create account on [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/), login and add your project to CI
2. Create `appveyor.yml` file in your root repository
3. In `yml` script you need to configure - `image, build_script, version`.
   Example:

```
image: Visual Studio 2019

build_script:
  - ps: dotnet --info
  - ps: dotnet restore VarEnc.sln
  - ps: dotnet build VarEnc.sln

version: 0.0.1.{build}
```

4. Add `deploy` section in your  `appveyor.yml` file

```
deploy:
- provider: NuGet
  server: path to nuget org your package
  api_key:
    secure: ...
  skip_symbols: true
  on:
    branch: master
- provider: NuGet
  name: production
  api_key:
    secure: ...
  on:
    branch: master
    appveyor_repo_tag: true
```

For more information about AppVeyor `publish` you can find in [official documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/nuget/) or helpful [article](https://andrewlock.net/publishing-your-first-nuget-package-with-appveyor-and-myget/) from Andrew Lock

#### Travis CI

The same situation for `Travis CI` tool, but yml file will be a little bit different.

1. The same step from `AppVeyor` approach
2. Create `.travis.yml` file in your root repository
3. Configure initial `yml` script

```
language: csharp
dist: xenial
sudo: required
solution: VarEnc.sln
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1

script:
 - dotnet --version
 - dotnet restore
 - dotnet build
```

4. Configure deploy in script. Solution you can find here - [How do I deploy nuget packages in Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509608/how-do-i-deploy-nuget-packages-in-travis-ci)

*Enjoy of configuring your CI in project!* [image: github]